# Accidentally deleted keyboard by King root

Tags: applications

I accidentally deleted my keyboard through king root how I install keyboard which is permanent and not removed by restoring

Comment: I've no idea what you mean with "not removed by restoring" – but if you've got a Google account configured on your device, you could always visit Playstore using a web browser on your computer and have it remotely install a keyboard app of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Go to Google Play Store and uninstall, then reinstall Google Keyboard.  Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open Google Play Store.  Tap on the menu icon in the upper left corner.  Tap on My Apps and Games.  You will see "Installed" and "All."  Tap on "All."  Scroll until you see Google Keyboard.  Tap "Enable" and re-download it.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a better solution, but I suggest (avoid messing with android system files) to reinstall *stock firmware* on your device using *fastboot* program and remember to take backup of your files to your google account.

If you don't know how to make boot and reinstall android firmware, I can help you that.